# CSS to make divs conform to chat layout

Tags: html, css

I want to hard code a chat session for language training purposes. I'm almost there but my messages are not fitting snugly into their parent divs. Specifically the height of the parent divs is not adjusting to accommodate the text.

```css
.my_left_div,
.my_right_div {
  margin: 10 0 10 0;
  width: 100%;
}

.my_left_div {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.my_right_div {
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.my_left_p {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.my_right_p {
  max-width: 200px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="my_left_div">
    <p class="my_left_p">left is the colour of my true love's hair</p>
  </div>
  <div class="my_right_div">
    <p class="my_right_p">right is the colour</p>
  </div>
  <div class="my_left_div">
    <p class="my_left_p">left is the colour of my true love's hair</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's what I get in WordPress:

[image: Screenshot]

I suppose it's possible that there is some WordPress theme CSS conflicting with my 'custom' CSS..

Answer (score 0):

```
.my_right_div {
  height: 72px;
  border:1px solid green;
}
```

After changing this your document will look like this [image: like this]

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/j2fLfy9y/8/

In order to make it responsive I prefer you to use position `relative`

```css
.my_left_div, .my_right_div {
  margin:10 0 10 0;
  width:100%;
}

.my_left_div {
    border: 1px solid red;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
}

.my_right_div {
    border: 1px solid green;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    left: 2px;
}

.my_left_p {
    max-width: 400px;
    margin-left: 3%;
}

.my_right_p {
    margin-right: 3%;
    float: right;
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="my_left_div">
    <p class="my_left_p">left is the colour of my true love's hair</p>
  </div>
  <div class="my_right_div">
    <p class="my_right_p">right is the colour... hairleft is the colour of my true love's hairhairleft is the colour of my true love's hair</p>
  </div>
  <div class="my_left_div">
    <p class="my_left_p">left is the colour of my true love's hair..left is the colour of my true love's hairleft is the colour of my true love's hair</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately the site won't let me do mark the answer, apparently because I'm new here and have 'less than 15 reputation'.